# LEFT JOIN with IN condition throws query processor error

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have the below sql query which fails to execute with error "The query processor ran out of internal resources and could not produce a query plan. This is a rare event and only expected for extremely complex queries or queries that reference a very large number of tables or partitions. Please simplify the query."

```
SELECT merchant.id,merchant.name,order.id,order.name,order.shipaddress 
FROM     orders AS order
LEFT JOIN 
merchants AS merchant 
ON
order.merchantid = merchant.id
WHERE
order.id IN (12 , 50 , 60 , 48,.. ...(upto 38000 id's)) 
ORDER BY order.id
```

The same query runs with left join condition or inner join conidtion fine ( and returns 65 records) if i remove the where condition.

It also runs fine with where condition included but only with inner join. Initially i thought its an issue with IN clause in WHERE condition but now i am a bit confused how LEFT is causing the issue.

Any help how i can fix this issue. One workaround is to insert all the records in WHERE clause to a temp table and use it as mentioned below. But is this problem related to the same ?

[The query processor ran out of internal resources exception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16830439/the-query-processor-ran-out-of-internal-resources-exception)

Comment: You should really store 38,000 ids in a table and use a `JOIN`, `IN`, or `EXISTS` on the table.  It will be much faster, especially if the table has an index.  And, the `left join` is superfluous, because the `WHERE` condition turns it into an inner join anyway.

Comment: I suppose a temp table is the way to go. ALso, there's a left join issue in your query, when left join put the right side table's conditions in the ON clause, i.e. move the WHERE clause condition to the ON clause (using AND) to get true left join behavior. As it is now you get regular inner join result.

Comment: Put your IDs into table variable and use `join`/`exists`.

Comment: "is this problem related to the same?" If you put your 38,000 IDs in a separate table, and your query runs without error, that's pretty good evidence that they are related.

Comment: The alias order may not be the best choice as it is also a T-SQL statement. Use o and m as aliases, much shorter anyway.

Comment: @Gordon Linoff Thanks for the reply. Could you please let me know how would this LEFT JOIN becomes inner join with where condition on it. I see it happening in Execution plan also. But want to know how it evaluates to that. Or a link to an example would also be fine.

Comment: I mean since its working with JOIN instead of LEFTJOIN which gives the same result as LEFT JOIN with WHERE clause , can i use the INNER JOIN safely in this scenario ?

Comment: Though it is working with INNER JOIN in SSMS window it fails in the c# code with same error

Comment: @krrishna . . . The query changed since I wrote that comment.  Now the `left join` is appropriate.

Answer (score 2):

You get this error because your `IN` clause is too large. According to the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/ms177682.aspx):

> Including an extremely large number of values (many thousands) in an
>   IN clause can consume resources and return errors 8623 or 8632. To
>   work around this problem, store the items in the IN list in a table.

As suggested in the comment, you should really be storing theses ids in a (temporary) table and join on them instead.